# Otimizando comportamento padrão do middleware

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho o seguinte middleware:

```
class OwnerOrAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $postId = $request->route('post');
        $post = $user->posts->find($postId);

        if ($user->id == 1 || (!is_null($post) && $post->user_id == $user->id)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->route('post.index')
                ->with(['status' => 'danger', 'mensagem' => 'Este post não te pertence!']);
    }
}
```

Basicamente este verificar se o usuário que vai editar um post é o Admin (id=1) ou se este é o dono do post.

Mas no meu controller sou obrigado a repetir praticamente a mesma consulta ao banco:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('painel.post.cad-edit', compact('post'));
}
```

Seria possível passar este valor para o controller como retorno do middleware?

Comment: A melhor forma de fazer isso é usando authorization ao invés do middleware. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization

Comment: mais tarde tarde faço uma resposta.

Comment: Tinha feito via authorization, porém, não gostei muito do resultado. Via middleware consigo validar e já indicar a mensagem do retorno aplicadas somente as rotas (resource) store, update e destroy. Quando fiz via authorization tive que "modificar" o controller, algo que gostaria de evitar se possível

Comment: Tentou fazer via Form Request?

Comment: Neste caso não atenderia. Por exemplo, no edit e destroy preciso passar somente o id do registro, sendo assim não faria muito sentido injetar um Request customizado.

Comment: `Seria possível passar este valor para o controller como retorno do middleware?` eu vi essa pergunta e li, reli, mas, cara sério **não** tem como, tudo que for feito para isso pode ficar estranho (*gambiarra*), até o seu `middleware` deveria retornar um erro não um `redirect` (deveria não é regra), talvez (**eu repito talvez**) fazer um `cache` para otimização da pesquisa pelo banco, mas, nunca testei pelo `Eloquent`. Se você está preocupado talvez com a repetição da `SQL` (`select * from posts where id = 1`)nesse caso não tem tantos problemas e a repetição do código são em momentos diferentes

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta para pergunta**

Não é possível.

Você deve retornar uma instância de `Illuminate\Http\Request` pois outros middlewares esperam uma instância dessa classe para continuar o seu trabalho. Se você passar qualquer outra coisa, eles vão ficar confusos e não vão saber o que fazer. Assim gerando um erro.

**Recomendação**

Já que essa duplicação é um problema no teu caso, recomendo você mover o código do middleware para teu controlador e dar um segunda chance para [authorizarion](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization) no Laravel. Pois para o que você está tentando fazer, essa é a funcionalidade recomendada pelo framework.